# Wiremock withQueryParam not matching regex

Tags: regex, wiremock

I'm trying to do this:

```
    stubFor(get("/my/path")
      .withQueryParam("paramName", matching(format("^(%s)|(%s)|(%s)$", v1, v2, v3)))
      .willReturn(okJson(RESPONSE)));
```

and I get this error:

```
GET                                                        | GET
/my/path                                                   | /my/path?paramName=v1Value  <<<<< URL does not match
                                                           |
Query: paramName [matches] ^(v1Value)|(v2Value)|(v3Value)$ | paramName: v1Value
```

I have tested the regex and it works. I also debugged and I saw that the RegexPattern also matches. But for some reason, I still get this error. I believe I'm using it wrongly.

I tried a simpler version that also didn't work:

```
stubFor(get("/my/path")
  .withQueryParam("paramName", equalTo("v1Value"))
  .willReturn(okJson(RESPONSE)));
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[WireMock documentation recommends matching on url path only and matching on query parameters separately.](http://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/#url-matching)

That would look something like...

```
    stubFor(get(urlPathEqualTo("/my/path"))
      .withQueryParam("paramName", matching(format("^(%s)|(%s)|(%s)$", v1, v2, v3)))
      .willReturn(okJson(RESPONSE)));
```

If I recall correctly, just using `stubFor(get("my/url"))` defaults to using `urlEqualTo`, which checks equality matching on path and query parameters

Comment: I checked the documentation, but I didn't pay attention to that detail, I checked the examples and there is no full example that would actually work. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! urlPathEqualTo, and you, saved the day.